# Какой движок выбрать?

Tags: интернет-магазин, cms, движок

Планируется создать магазин со свободными ценами, какой движок выбрать для этого? 
Те цены назначает клиент. А админ уже одобряет и тд...

Answer (score 2):

В вопросах выбора движков рекомендую найти знакомого толкового программиста и разработать движок исходя из **своих** требований, потому что иначе бывают разные конфузы.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCart - что ни на есть... Легкое MVC решение.. Модернизируется просто... Мой протеже разобрался в нем быстрее чем я успел сказать "Вот смотри это движок магазина"

Comment: Мой коллега по работе с радостью кинулся на OpenCart и первые 10 минут радовался как младенец: "Как всё просто!". Потом начал копать глубже и уже через минет 15 стал плеваться. Не факт, что у коллеги руки не из ... Поэтому рекомендую подольше "пощупать" OpenCart прежде чем остановить на ней выбор.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться в движке интернет магазина Magento. Это просто ад. Посмотрите, может быть вам понравится?)